# Want to show data in combo box from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show a combo box data from mysql table. Below is the code.
But it is not working.i am unable to find the error. can anyone please help me.

```
    <select name="priority">
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '1amShaw0n';
$db = 'shawon_logindb';
$db = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo isset($row["username"])?$row["username"]:''; ?>">   <?php echo isset($row["username"])?$row["username"]:''; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code!!!

Comment: use $db= mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");  in ur code replace values accordingly, also you have used var $db two times change it

Answer (score 1):

1. Conflicting  `mysql` and `mysqli`.
2. There is two values  in `$db` variable.
3. Remove `isset` inside `<option>`, because its only execute when its having data.

   ```
       $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");

       $query = "SELECT * FROM members";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
       {
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">   <?php echo $row["username"]; ?></option>
       <?php
       }
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$db = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";
$result = $db->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo isset($row['username']) ? $row['username'] : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($row["username"]) ? $row["username"] : ''; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Don't mix the `mysql` & `mysqli` functions.